# iOS - Converting HTML to Normal text

Tags: html, ios, text, html-content-extraction

In my application, I'm receiving an html file from a news server.

After receiving, I want to remove the tags, images, URL anchors, etc and just show the text in text view.

There's a [website](http://www.webtoolhub.com/tn561393-html-to-text-converter.aspx) which functions similar to the one that I'm looking for. The website takes html as input and removes the tags and displays just plain text as result. I want to achieve similar function in my app and display only the text from the news received.

Any libraries or open source web services available for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this library [here](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText), you could do something like this:

```
NSString *htmlStripped = [[NSAttributedString attributedStringWithHTML:DATA_FOR_MY_HTML options:nil] string];
```